# Click is working on each nested child, how to click only closest child using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have nested div with same class now i want to access only closest child how can i do that?

My Code:-

```js
 $('.cat-item').click(function() {
            $(this).find('.sub-menu').toggle();
        });
```

```css
.sub-menu{ display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="category-menu">
                        <li class="cat-item">
                            <a href="#">Food Service Disposables</a>
                            <ul class="sub-menu">
                                <li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Healthcare &amp; Medical </a>
                                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                                        <li class="cat-item"><a href=" # ">Food Service Disposables</a></li>
                                        <li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Healthcare &amp; Medical </a>
                                            <ul class="sub-menu">
                                                <li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Healthcare &amp; Medical</a></li>
                                                <li class="cat-item"><a href=" # ">Food Service Disposables</a></li>
                                                <li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Hygiene &amp; Cleaning</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Hygiene &amp; Cleaning</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="cat-item has-children"><a href=" # ">Food Service Disposables</a></li>
                                <li class="cat-item has-children"><a href="#">Hygiene &amp; Cleaning</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="cat-item has-children">
                            <a href="#">Healthcare &amp; Medical</a>

                        </li>
                        <li class="cat-item has-children">
                            <a href="#">Hygiene &amp; Cleaning </a>
                            <ul class="sub-menu">
                                <li class="cat-item has-children"><a href="#">Healthcare &amp; Medical</a></li>
                                <li class="cat-item has-children"><a href=" # ">Food Service Disposables</a></li>
                                <li class="cat-item has-children"><a href="#">Hygiene &amp; Cleaning</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
```

Thanks for your Efforts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can target the `a` tag selector using `$('.cat-item a')` for the click as each of your nested list items parent has an a tag for the clickable element as its first child element and then use `$(this).next().toggle('sub-menu')`.

```js
$('.cat-item a').click(function() {
  $(this).next().toggle('sub-menu')
})
```

```css
.sub-menu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="category-menu">
  <li class="cat-item">
    <a href="#">Food Service Disposables</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Healthcare &amp; Medical </a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li class="cat-item"><a href=" # ">Food Service Disposables</a></li>
          <li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Healthcare &amp; Medical </a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Healthcare &amp; Medical</a></li>
              <li class="cat-item"><a href=" # ">Food Service Disposables</a></li>
              <li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Hygiene &amp; Cleaning</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="cat-item"><a href="#">Hygiene &amp; Cleaning</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="cat-item has-children"><a href=" # ">Food Service Disposables</a></li>
      <li class="cat-item has-children"><a href="#">Hygiene &amp; Cleaning</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="cat-item has-children">
    <a href="#">Healthcare &amp; Medical</a>

  </li>
  <li class="cat-item has-children">
    <a href="#">Hygiene &amp; Cleaning </a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li class="cat-item has-children"><a href="#">Healthcare &amp; Medical</a></li>
      <li class="cat-item has-children"><a href=" # ">Food Service Disposables</a></li>
      <li class="cat-item has-children"><a href="#">Hygiene &amp; Cleaning</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```